# How to understand the font specification in Emacs?

Tags: fonts

I can find the font specification of a character in Emacs as something like

```
mac-ct:-*-Source Code Pro-normal-normal-normal-*-20-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1 (#x30)
```

What do the different parts of it mean?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24295/230197 and the last three sub-nodes of [`(elisp) Faces`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces.html). In brief, the format is courtesy of the X Window System, not Emacs.

Comment: See [X logical font description (xlfd)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwja-aah7_HXAhXj8YMKHfzIBT8QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FX_logical_font_description&usg=AOvVaw0ekzCaV47Zja5on6DAE0kq) and Emacs function `x-decompose-font-name`.

Comment: See also [`(emacs) Fonts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html) and the sub-nodes of [`(emacs) International`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/International.html) pertaining to fontsets.